# clearInterlval не срабатывает второй раз

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, setinterval, clearinterval

`clearInterlval()` не срабатывает второй раз при наведении курсора

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x =  function(){
         $("#animate").animate({'left':'+=1'},10)
    };

    var run = setInterval( x,10);   

    $("#animate").mouseover(function(){
        clearInterval(run);
        console.log('true');
    });
    $("#animate").mouseleave(function(){
        var run = setInterval( x,10); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d2nhe1g2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` внутри функции делает переменную доступную только внутри самой функции, а вам нужна глобальная `run` переменная.

Замените

```
$("#animate").mouseleave(function(){
    var run = setInterval( x,10); 
});
```

на

```
$("#animate").mouseleave(function(){
    run = setInterval( x,10); 
});
```

Comment: Тарас, если ответ Вам подошел, поставьте галочку как принятый . Это пометит вопрос в системе как отвеченный. и он больше встплывать не будет... иначе через год он опять поднимется как неотвеченный :) Спасибо